# How can I annotate a method that returns self so that the stub file shows correct return types?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Pretext: This code is useless, and the use case might be useless also, but I am just trying to figure out how to make it work so that the stub files are showing the correct signatures. The question seems confusing, so I am trying my best to explain, but am very open to suggestions to make the question structure better.

Environment:
Python: 3.7.9
Mypy
Vscode + Pylance

Directory structure:

```
 .
├──  1.py
└──  testcode
   ├──  __init__.py
   └──  modules
      ├──  __init__.py
      └──  something.py
```

Inside `1.py`

```py
from testcode import Entry

e = Entry('a').a_function().b_function().c_function()
```

Inside `__init__.py`

```py
from .modules.something import Something, AnotherThing

class Entry(Something, AnotherThing):
    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self.a = a
```

In this case, the `return self` is the instance of `Entry`. When I do not specify the return type in `b_function` (or a, b, c function), the type hints are correct.

[image]

But when I specify the return type as `Entry`, the return type shows as `Any`

`something.py` with return types annotated:

```py
class Something(object):
    def a_function(self) -> 'Entry':
        return self

    def b_function(self) -> 'Entry':
        return self

class AnotherThing:
    def c_function(self) -> 'Entry':
        return self
```

[image]

So to try and overcome this, I tried creating stub files using `stubgen` with the command `stubgen -o . -p testcode` which creates all the `pyi` files, and `something.pyi` includes:

```py
class Something:
    def a_function(self) -> Entry: ...
    def b_function(self) -> Entry: ...

class AnotherThing:
    def c_function(self) -> Entry: ...
```

Directory after stub generation:

```
 .
├──  1.py
└──  testcode
   ├──  __init__.py
   ├──  __init__.pyi
   └──  modules
      ├──  __init__.py
      ├──  __init__.pyi
      ├──  something.py
      └──  something.pyi
```

Now I understand why this doesnt work, because when i specify the return type of `Entry` in a method for `Something`, python doesnt know what `Entry` is which can be seen in the next screenshot. So it assigns the `Any` type to it:

[image]

#### Question:

Knowing that when the return type of `Entry` is not annotated in a method for `Something`, it picks up the correct return type (and hence provides nice intellisense), how can I annotate and generate stubfiles correctly so that it doesnt return `Any` when a return type of self is annotated?

#### Edit:

To reflect on the first answer, binding the subclasses does not fully solve the problem because the intellisense and types will show only the called methods methods. So for example, if I call `a_function`, `c_function` will not show, and vice versa. When I dont type hint on the return types of the `Something` and `AnotherThing` class, and vscode correctly assumes `Entry` is the return type, then i can get intellisense for `c_function` when I call `a_function`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mypy: is there some way to implement a 'SelfType' TypeVar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532917/mypy-is-there-some-way-to-implement-a-selftype-typevar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make the `self` parameter of your `Something` and `AnotherThing` functions bound to a subclass of those classes using a `TypeVar` like so:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


ST = TypeVar('ST', bound='Something')

class Something:
    def a_function(self: ST) -> ST:
        return self

    def b_function(self: ST) -> ST:
        return self

AT = TypeVar('AT', bound='AnotherThing')

class AnotherThing:
    def c_function(self: AT) -> AT:
        return self
```

More info can be found [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self).

Comment: Thanks! I would accept this as an answer, but there is a slight problem. When I bound `ST` and `AT` to `Something` and `AnotherThing` respectfully, the type hints and intellisense will show the methods for the respective class. For example, if i call `a_function`, `c_function` will not show up anymore. That is what I am trying to overcome. I will update the OP to include a screenshot.

Comment: What I need to do is bind the `Entry` class from init to replicate the default untyped behavior from vscode.

Comment: I'm not getting the same result. When I copy and paste the code above from this answer into `something.py`, the code in `1.py` is showing the correct intellisense for each subsequent function call (return type of `Entry`). I do however see the same result from your edit if I don't annotate the `self` param with `self: ST` and `self: AT` in the `Something` and `AnotherThing` functions, respectively. Perhaps this was left out in your test?

Comment: You are right. I did forget to annotate `self` itself.